# Is there a way to add quick replies/suggestion chips (like actions on Google) in Discord chat

Tags: dialogflow-es, discord, discord.js, actions-on-google, chatbot

I am making a Discord bot, and I was wondering if there was a way to add suggestion chips/quick replies so that people could click the bubble and that would be sent as a reply.

[image: Chatbot with suggested replies]

My end goal is to use DialogFlow's Actions on Google ability to create suggestion buttons, but that would only be possible if discord supported quick replies in the first place.

I am using discord.js for the bot as of now.

One other thing I was thinking was to add some sort of HTML snippet inside bot response, that would call another webpage which has the fully functioning bot in it, all displayed inside Discord. Or HTML embeds that would have suggestion chips that could then be sent as a response.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think suggestion buttons like in the image are possible. However, reactions are commonly used.

For example, the bot can say

> How can I assist you today?
>
> 1️⃣: Just browsing!
>
> 2️⃣: I have question
>
> 3️⃣: Give me a Product Tour

and the bot can respond when the user reacts with the appropriate emoji.

For more information on how to implement this, see [the Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200308140944/https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors)).